# Centering a specific list item

Tags: css

I have a horizontal list with each item having the same width. I'm using `direction: rtl;` to have the container element go from right to left.

I want it so the middle (2nd) item is positioned to the centre of the page. My problem when the combined LI's hold more width than the users screen width, it does not align correctly. e.g. http://jsbin.com/vijedisito/edit?css,output (toggle the CSS tab).

So in a nutshell, I'm wanting to have the orange block align to the purple block, however this fails when the users screen width is too small.

Is there a better way to do this?

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size:0;
  text-align: center;
  background:black;
 }
ul {
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:block;
  background:black;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 500px;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: orange;
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.test {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.test > span {
  display:block;
  width:500px;
  background: purple;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
    <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  
  <span class="test">
    <span></span>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the width rule on your LI's to: `33.33%` instead of 500px.

Here is an example:

http://codepen.io/nathanfelix/pen/GZQoNQ

I assume that this is what you mean?

Comment: No. I'll be adding LI's items dynamically, but to begin with there will only be 3.

Comment: Check my other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CSS flex property.

`display: flex;` on the container and `flex-grow:1;` on the LI's

Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/nathanfelix/pen/bpLERQ

Answer (score 0):

window/html's width can become less than the ul width. to avoid this, you may reset display on html to allow it to grow wider than window and then use coordonates to set position of your absolute element:

```css
/* CSS UPDATE */

html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* END UPDATE */

.test > span {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  background: purple;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
}
ul {
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 500px;
}
li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: orange;
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span class="test">
    <span></span>
</span>
```

*for the idea to keep **one random li** from a random numbers of them **in the flow but in the middle**, i do not think that CSS will help you here. At least, it seems unclear to me what you really look for, **do you have any examples to clear up the question** ?*